Installing grub on an image works, but there's no menu
I have a script that I've been using for years to generate image files that get installed on other machines. The script uses debootstrap, then makes some customizations. On Bionic, it installed grub on legacy MBR partitions. With Focal, I changed the images to GPT partitions and used the following to install grub. These commands are run in the chroot:
(chroot)# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
(chroot)# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi \
                       --boot-directory=/boot \
                       --efi-directory=/boot/efi \
                       --bootloader-id=debian \
                       --recheck \
                       --no-nvram \
                       --removable <loopback device for the image file>

That worked perfectly fine. Recently I was updating my scripts for Noble, and now I get a strange behavior. When I install the image on a machine and boot it, I don't get a grub menu. It goes straight to the grub prompt. If I then type normal, it does not go to a grub menu, but it does boot.
I can't figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. It seems like grub works and boots my system, it just... insists on going to the prompt first?
If I use the stock Noble installer instead of my image, I can see it running the following:
Using grub install command: /usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install
Grub install cmds:
[['efibootmgr', '-v'], ['dpkg-reconfigure', 'grub-efi-amd64'], ['update-grub'], ['/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install'], ['efibootmgr', '-v']]

update-grub is the same as grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg, so that's not it. grub-multi-install doesn't seem to apply here, since I don't need to boot from multiple disks.
If I boot one of my imaged machines and run:
$ sudo /usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install
Trying to migrate /boot/efi into esp config
Installing grub to /boot/efi.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

Then it actually boots without sitting at the prompt!
The way I read this, despite the fact that this used to work, I now need to run grub-multi-install to get grub to not sit at a prompt forever. I don't understand why that would be the case given that the grub-install step is independent of the menu configuration. Also, I'm concerned about using grub-multi-install in my image build script, because it seems like it'd just install itself on all available devices, including the build host, which I do not want.
Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?
